# Drinfeld's 1988 letter to Schechtman: translation request

Tags: translation, soft-question

Inspired by an [old question by Kevin Lin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9171/idea-for-book-translation-project-closed) and the [communal translation of an answer by Laurent Fargues](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10913/lifting-the-p-torsion-of-a-supersingular-elliptic-curve/11097#11097), I am proposing a communal effort to translate from Russian to English Drinfeld's famous 1988 letter to Schechtman: [typeset](http://math.harvard.edu/~tdp/Drinfeld-Letter.to.Schechtman.on.New.directions.of.work-1988.pdf) and [in the handwritten original](http://math.harvard.edu/~tdp/original.pdf).

I am starting a blank, communal answer below in which to whip up the translation. Thanks in advance for any contributions!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to offer $100 to a grad school classmate who is fluent in Russian to do it in one sitting?

Comment: Thanos, it could be helpful if you put the Russian version in TeX (as it has plenty of formulas) and then Russian text is translated. Isn't the TeX source unavailable?

Comment: @Boyarsky: That is a good suggestion, but I wanted to experiment with MO first.

Comment: @Wadim: Only the answer needs to be in community wiki, since only the answer needs to be edited by the community. But to keep my motives above any suspicions, I'm making it community wiki.

Comment: @Wadim: I'm afraid I haven't been able to procure the .tex source of the letter.

Comment: There is inevitably going to be some debate. I've preemptively started the meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/477/drinfelds-1988-letter-to-schechtman-translation-request/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keith Conrad has kindly produced a translation available [here](https://www.doi.org/10.4171/EMSS/5). It can be cited as

> Vladimir Drinfeld, *A letter from Kharkov to Moscow.* EMS Surv. Math. Sci. **1** (2014), 241-248. doi:[10.4171/EMSS/5](https://www.doi.org/10.4171/EMSS/5)

Comment: Translation done and sent to Thanos.  Move on to other business, folks!

Comment: KConrad or Thanos, would one of you please post the translation publicly?

Comment: It has been submitted to russian authorities for review; stay tuned! 

Comment: I'm afraid I failed to obtain permission to distribute the translation of the letter publicly.

Comment: Permission obtained!

Comment: If native speakers can post comments indicating any mistakes in translation (once Thanos posts links to original versions of the letters) then they will be taken into account.

Comment: There are no real mistakes (except, perhaps, for some algebraic terminology that I know in neither language, so I cannot tell anything there) but some colorful language and cultural references are lost. Unfortunately, to restore them properly, would require more knowledge of the English slang and idioms than I have. 

Comment: I changed the link to a doi link (so it would be more stable) and added the full citation.