# Deligne's letter to Jean-Pierre Serre

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, galois-representations, nt.number-theory

I'm looking for [another](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54402/delignes-letter-to-piatetskii-shapiro-from-1973) letter of Pierre Deligne, this time to Jean-Pierre Serre (from around 1974 I think), in which he proves that the Galois representation associated to a certain Hecke eigenform is of specific form at p. This letter is mentioned, for example, in the remark 1.4 in [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/vigregroup/vigre05/edixhoven4.pdf), or in the paper of B. Gross "A tameness criterion for Galois representations associated to modular forms (mod p)".

Additional question: Is it the same letter that is mentioned in Buzzard, Gee "[The conjectural connections between automorphic representations and Galois representations](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/papers/bgagsvn.pdf)"?

I will be grateful for your help.

edit: I'm pushing the question up. Does anyone have the mentioned letter?

Comment: The letter mentioned in Buzzard-Gee is a different letter, written only a few years ago. 

Comment: In retrospect, your comment shows me that we should have said something like "a 2007 letter from Deligne to Serre" or something. Thanks. I'll change this before it appears in print.

Comment: PS I've never seen the actual 1974 letter.

Comment: I wonder if we'll ever start getting these kind of questions about e-mails.

Comment: PPS I wish we could edit comments. PPPS I think all the material in the letter will be covered in places like Mazur-Wiles.

Comment: @Gunnar: I've definitely seen "[X]: personal communication from X" in references, so I would conjecture that the answer would be yes.

Comment: @Kevin: I sometimes use the "poor-man's method" of editing comments: I copy the text of the old comment into a new comment, edit it, post the revised version, and delete the old comment.

Comment: @Kevin: thank you for your answer. So now I'd be glad to see both letters of Deligne to Serre ;).

Comment: The result on the form of the Gal rep at p is proved in Mazur–Wiles' *On $p$-adic analytic families of Gal reps* (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=860140) with some restrictions, and in Wiles' paper *On ordinary λ-adic repss associated to modular forms* (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=969243) without hypotheses in the Hilbert modular case. A proof is also sketched in Hida's book *Geometric modular forms and elliptic curves* Theorem 4.2.7 (together with a new proof of the existence of the Gal reps based on an idea of Shimura's). In particular, the ingredients are...

Comment: (cont'd) modular Jacobians, pseudo-representations, Hida theory, etc. So, this is not Deligne's proof. But if all you want is some proof of this result, there you go.

Comment: @Rob: thank you, it will be useful, but I would like to see Deligne's letter(s) anyway.

Comment: What about kindly asking directly to Deligne?

Comment: Dear Przemyslaw, I have a copy of the letter (which I got from Dick Gross many years ago).  I can send one to you.  (I should have time
in the next week or so.)

Regards, Matthew

P.S. Its arguments are different to those in the literature, e.g. in Mazur and/or Wiles.  It more directly uses $p$-adic vanishing cycles.


Comment: Dear Matthew, thank you, I will be very grateful. I've read that the arguments are a bit different in that letter and that's why I'd like to see it.

Comment: Why the bump of the question. Did the solution suggested in the last comments fail for some reason? 

Comment: Is this letter publicly available by now? I came up with a similar question recently, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116017/delignes-letter-to-looijenga-from-1974, and then started a section in Deligne's wiki page on his hand-written letters (though I am not quite sure if this is the appropriate place to collect them). I would very much appreciate if someone having the letter -- and the permission to publish it -- would link it here and on the wiki page!

Comment: I haven't got it finally as I changed the way to attack the problem I had in mind. But still, I'd be very interested in seeing it. Also I would like to see other Deligne's letters if possible and it would be nice to have a place to collect them all (of course, with a permission of the author).

Comment: Might it be [this letter](https://web.archive.org/web/20150330055922/http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/richarz/DeligneAnSerreFeb74.pdf)?