# Albrecht Fröhlich's text `Groupoids, groupoid spaces and cohomology' (1965)

Tags: ct.category-theory, group-cohomology, groupoids, nonabelian-cohomology

I am looking for Albrecht Fröhlich's  unpublished text `Groupoids, groupoid spaces and cohomology' (1965). In this text Fröhlich defines cohomology of a group with coefficients in a groupoid (this was later generalized by Ronald Brown to cohomology of a groupoid with coefficients in a groupoid). I would be grateful if someone could put this text on the Net.

Comment: I don't think MathOverflow is the right place for such requests.

Comment: Why are you looking for it?  Maybe there is a substitute if you have a specific topic you're looking for.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: I was inspired by the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54402/delignes-letter-to-piatetskii-shapiro-from-1973/54541#54541 on Deligne's letter to Piatetskii-Shapiro. Users answered by scanning and uploading the Russian translation and the English original, and no one complained...

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained my misgivings, and now I have forgotten what they were.  I think I was concerned about publishing unpublished work without the author's permission, but that does not seem to be particularly relevant in this case.